# Javascript: What exactly is paymentRequest? Associative Array? JSON object?

Tags: javascript

I have a little experience programming in other languages but I am learning Javascript.

I am seeing this line

```
 var runningAmount  = 42;
 var subTotalDescr  = "Test Goodies";

 var paymentRequest = {
   currencyCode: 'USD',
   countryCode: 'US',
   requiredShippingContactFields: ['postalAddress','email', 'name', 'phone'],
   lineItems: [{label: subTotalDescr, amount: runningAmount }],
   total: {
      label: 'Shoes',
      amount: getTotal()
   },
   supportedNetworks: ['amex', 'masterCard', 'visa' ],
   merchantCapabilities: [ 'supports3DS', 'supportsEMV', 'supportsCredit', 'supportsDebit' ]
};
```

I see that elements as `subTotalDescr` and `runningAmount` are other variables and `getTotal()` is a function.

So, these elements will be read and compose `paymentRequest` var, but what exactly is `paymentRequest`? A JSON object, an associative array?

Excuse me if the question is stupid. thanks.

Comment: ah, I see. thanks. Please make this comment an answer. Thanks.

Comment: downvote? Wow. One has to know everything.

Comment: Sure, I was looking for a duplicate but I can't really find one.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substituent for a language tutorial, you should learn the fundamental syntax of the language you're trying to work in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, there are objects. There's no associative array type. There are arrays with a length and numeric property names, but they're also objects. JSON is a serialization format and doesn't have bearing on JavaScript values. The syntax

```
var something = {
  propertyName: 0,
  // ...
};
```

is an *object initializer*, and the result is an object. There are other ways of creating objects too, using constructor functions and as of a few years ago with the `class` mechanisms. Still, for the most part, they're just objects.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is amazing, it's very cool you are learning it.

JavaScript isn't statically-typed. In this case, `paymentRequest` is a variable object. Although it looks like JSON, you are only attributing some properties with values. In this case, the `currencyCode` propery is set to `'USD'`. You can add more properties, which can pretty much be anything, including references to itself or other objects, values or functions.

If you want to learn more I can suggest:

1. The Net Ninja, he is amazing at teaching code.
2. The [Mozilla JavaScipt Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), its a little bit more technical but a great resource once you get a hang of it.
3. Once you get into really technical stuff, I recomend checking the official ECMA docs, like [ECMA2021](https://tc39.es/ecma262/). But dont forget to check the backwards compatibility.

> Blockquote